# Passing txtBox values between forms

Tags: c#

I have always had trouble with this issue, i think i need to learn how it works, i have FormMain (my main form) and a second form (FormAddUrls) when i open form2 (FormAddUrls) i want to pass the multitextbox value back to the main form (FormMain)

I know in VB it's as simple as saying: **FormMain.txtBoxUrls.Text = finalOutput;** but not as easy in C#.

(form1) - FormMain

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WraithProjectCreator;
using IronPdf;
using System.Text;

namespace GSAProjectCreator
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        private IniParser m_Parser = null;

        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnShowUrlsForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormAddUrls fau = new FormAddUrls();
            fau.Show();
        }

     }
}
```

(form2) - FormAddUrls

```
using GSAProjectCreator;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WraithProjectCreator
{
    public partial class FormAddUrls : Form
    {
        public FormAddUrls()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddUrls_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("{");
            foreach (string line in txtBoxURLsMass.Lines)
            {
                //Helpers.returnMessage(line);
                builder.Append(line + "|");
            }
            builder.Append("}");
            string finalOutput = "";
            if (builder.ToString().Contains("|}")) {
                finalOutput = builder.ToString().Replace("|}", "}");
            }
            //FormMain.txtBoxUrls.Text = finalOutput;
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

I have ommited a lot of form1's code to leave the basic structure, i'm trying to pass back **finalOutput** from form2 to form1 (the txtBoxUrls.Text) text box, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use the main form - you could have a static property which you could set (which would update the text for *all* main form instances).

If you only have one main form, and have a reference to it when you create the FormAddUrls object then you should just change the constructor to accept a MainForm (or as generic a type as possible), store the reference as a field and update the property on it when the button is clicked:

```
 public partial class FormAddUrls : Form
 {
     private readonly Form _parentForm;
     public FormAddUrls(MainForm parent)
     {
         _parentForm = parent;
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void btnAddUrls_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         builder.Append("{");
         foreach (string line in txtBoxURLsMass.Lines)
         {
             //Helpers.returnMessage(line);
             builder.Append(line + "|");
         }
         builder.Append("}");
         string finalOutput = "";
         if (builder.ToString().Contains("|}")) {
             finalOutput = builder.ToString().Replace("|}", "}");
         }
         if(_parentForm != null)
             _parentForm.txtBoxUrls.Text = finalOutput;
         this.Close();
     }

 }
```